# Opening Google Maps for Android Navigation with multiple coordinates as waypoints

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know if this is possible or now.

Right now I am opening the Google Maps with navigation from current user location to a defined set of coordinates like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + String.valueOf(getDestinationLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(getDestinationLongitude())));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.NavigationActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to to have multiple sets of coordinates between current location and a final destination, so go to point a, point b and then finally destination point c. ?

Comment: Hi,did you get any solution for this problem?I have some problem

Comment: did you find any solution I have some problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple waypoints along the way to a certain destination. This can be achieved by using the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). This is the API that would also give you the [legs[]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Legs) and the [steps[]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Steps) array which helps you in properly implementing and returning probable paths from source to the destination covering all the waypoints along the way.

For a sample implementation, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints).